# Unable to Retrieve/download the actual recording Media Twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

```
const Twilio = require('twilio');
const request = require('request');

const apiKeySid = 'SKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const apiKeySecret = 'your_api_key_secret';
const accountSid = 'ACb46a83261c60f3a45ce47eccac8a913d';
const client = new Twilio(apiKeySid, apiKeySecret, { accountSid: 
accountSid });

const roomSid = 'RMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const recordingSid = 'RTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const uri = 'https://video.twilio.com/v1/' +
        `Rooms/${roomSid}/` +
        `Recordings/${recordingSid}` +
        '/Media';
const response = client.request({ method: "POST", uri: uri });
const mediaLocation = JSON.parse(response.body).location;

request.get(mediaLocation, (err, res, media) => {
console.log(media);
});
```

I tried to retrieve recorded media but this is not working and getting undefined when I am printing response.body.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Apologies, that is a mistake in our documentation. Calling `client.request` is an asynchronous call and returns a `Promise`.

Try this instead:

```
client.request({ method: "GET", uri: uri }).then(response => {
  const mediaLocation = JSON.parse(response.body).location;
  request.get(mediaLocation, (err, res, media) => {
    console.log(media);
  });
});
```

I've started [a pull request to get this back into the documentation here too](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/api-snippets/pull/529/files).

Answer (score 0):

@philnash I tried this above code block but getting "mediaLocation" as undefined.
Changed **JSON.parse(response.body).location** to **JSON.parse(response.body).redirect_to** and it's working.

```
 client.request({ method: "GET", uri: uri }).then((response) => {
 const mediaLocation = JSON.parse(response.body).redirect_to;
 request.get(mediaLocation, (err, res, media) => {
  console.log(media);
 });
});
```

response:

```
{ statusCode: 302,
body: '{"redirect_to": 
"https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx…….”}’ }
```